# Running cmake while building Docker alpine container, get error: "make: /usr/bin/make: Operation not permitted ... Error 127"

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, alpine-linux

While attempting to update a `Docker` container for `alpine:3.17`, `cmake` reports the following when building the container from its Dockerfile:

```
 [build 8/8] RUN cmake     -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release     ../examples/server  && make:
#13 0.549 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
#13 0.592 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
#13 0.602 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
#13 0.613 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
#13 0.614 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
#13 0.625 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
#13 0.625 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
#13 0.625   The C compiler
#13 0.625
#13 0.625     "/usr/bin/cc"
#13 0.625
#13 0.625   is not able to compile a simple test program.
#13 0.625
#13 0.625   It fails with the following output:
#13 0.625
#13 0.625     Change Dir: /opt/via-httplib/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
#13 0.625
#13 0.625     Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_9cb53/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb53.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9cb53.dir/build
#13 0.625     make: /usr/bin/make: Operation not permitted
#13 0.625     make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_9cb53/fast] Error 127
```

I found: [make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12396) which indicates that it's an `alpine` issue: [faccessat2](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0#faccessat2) introduced in release 3.14.

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows, how can I fix this without reverting to `alpine:3.13`?

Comment: Do you have some steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes @digby280, try to build a docker container using the Dockerfile in the develop branch of https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib edited to use alpine:3.17

Comment: It works for me.  I tried it on both Windows and Linux.  I am using the latest docker 20.10.22.  Try upgrading docker if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks @digby280 that's good to know. I'll double check my docker installation.